# Как через функцию js узнать id родительского объекта

Tags: javascript

Имеется два id в коде

```
<div id="content_button">
<a href="#" class="boton1" id="temp" onClick=tt(id);>Принять</a>
</div>
```

и функция, которая получает id элемента.

```
function tt (id) {
console.log (id)
console.log(id.parentNode.getAttribute('id') );
    }
```

Как через эту функцию можно узнать id родительского элемента. Если я пытаюсь добавить `parentNode` и `this`, то у меня выходит ошибка parentNode is undefined

Comment: Если `id` на входе функции это элемент, то `id.parentNode.id`. Если это просто строка `document.querySelector(\`#${id}\`).parentNode.id`

Answer (score 3):

```js
function tt(element) {
  console.log(element.id, element.parentNode.id, element.closest("*").id)
}
```

```css
#content_button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_button">
  <a href="#" class="boton1" id="temp" onClick="tt(this)">Принять</a>
</div>
```

Comment: а closest - это тоже родитель ?

Comment: @MaximLensky `closest(...)` - это элемент в цепочке вложенных элементов, начиная с себя, в направлении корня.